# Are the data controls in webforms part of Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I was wondering if the data controls in webforms are part of Entity Framework? I mean is there a difference between Native SQL in EF and a form view control?

Comment: Entity Framework is an O/RM `Object Relational Mapper`. And it's not directly related to data controls in web forms. So the simple answer is - No!

Comment: this is like asking "are the wheels part of the car engine?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I am sorry for a basic question, I am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No those are completely different products, totally unrelated.  One is for presenting data (form view control), and one is for querying data from the database (EF).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Aren't you still querying the database with form view control?

Comment: The SqlDataSource control does query the database yes, so technically, that is correct.  However, I personally recommend never to use it.  I personally keep the ASP.NET code separate from the database query code, and pass up the results of the query to a Grid or form.